# Where to dispatch multiple actions in redux?

Tags: javascript, redux

I am using redux with `connect` and `redux-thunk` middleware and containers.

Currently when a user perform an action, example one click on a button, I need to dispatch that action (sync) which will dispatch other few actions (asynch).

I am aware dispatching actions from within the reducer is an anti pattern.

I would like to know what is a suitable place for this code.

Currently I am not sure if it should stay in:

- The action creator.
- In the container using store.subscribe.

Comment: I believe [this](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html) describes the exact pattern you're looking for. Just read that page, the part you're most interested in is probably where they describe the `fetchPosts` function.

Comment: @saadq thanks for your link, it looks like in the action creator... correct?

Comment: Bear in mind that `dispatch` is a **SYNCHRONOUS** operation :)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The recommended way as per the [documentation](https://redux.js.org/advanced/asyncactions#async-action-creators) is in the action creator, like so:

```
function actionCreator(payload) {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(action1(payload))
        dispatch(action2(payload))
    }
}
```

Then you would probably want to attach the action creators as prop and pass it down to the container using `mapDispatchToProps` like in the example mentioned [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/using-react-redux/connect-dispatching-actions-with-mapDispatchToProps.md). So it would look something like so:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
   action1: some_payload => dispatch(action1(some_payload))
   action2: some_payload => dispatch(action2(some_payload))
})

// your component
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(YourApp)
```

---

Comment: Unfortunately the first link is broken. Should it point to https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.md ?

Comment: Consider adding the code here as well, not just linking the documentation

Comment: What's the best way of writing unit tests for multiple dispatches?

Comment: @Shiraz one example is in the documentation: https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests#async-action-creators

Comment: @Mμ.By providing a Promise.Resolve() response to your example actionCreator it then becomes possible to test it using the pattern shown in https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests#async-action-creators. I've now provided an answer to the OP question with suggested code - maybe I should also add some unit test code?!

Answer (score 21):

As other pointed out `The action creator` is the right place for dispatching multiple actions.

Below an example of how `action1` could dispatch other actions in your `action creator`.

```
const action1 = id => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(action2(id))
    dispatch(action3(id))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

The action creator is the correct location for dispatching multiple actions. Although code like the following would work:

```
function actionCreator(payload) {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(action1(payload))
        dispatch(action2(payload))
    }
}
```

I would highly recommend `redux-thunk` based action creators to always return a resolved Promise, so that such action creators can be part of another async call. So, the simplest update to the above would be:

```
function actionCreator(payload) {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(action1(payload));
        dispatch(action2(payload));
        return Promise.resolve();
    }
}
```

It would then be possible to dispatch to the above with:
`actionCreator(payload).then(doAnotherAction(anotherPayload))`
or the following, if we need to maintain order of calls:
`actionCreator(payload).then(() => doAnotherAction(anotherPayload))`

If you wish to 'future-proof' your action creator, so that it could handle calling both async and sync action creators, you could write it as:

```
function actionCreator(payload) {
    return dispatch =>
        Promise.resolve(dispatch(action1(payload))).then(
        () => dispatch(action2(payload)));
}
```

And, if you like ES6 arrow notation the above can be defined as:

```
const actionCreator = payload => dispatch =>
        Promise.resolve(dispatch(action1(payload))).then(
        () => dispatch(action2(payload)));
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer man. I was really searching a way of doing multiple dispatch in series and also in order.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a [Promise Middleware](https://github.com/klis87/redux-saga-requests#promise-middleware-arrow_up), you can use this syntax so you're able to use `.then()` on your `dispatch(topLevelAction())`:

```
export const topLevelAction = () => dispatch => {
    return Promise.all([dispatch(action1()), dispatch(action2()), dispatch(action3())])
}
```

Answer (score 3):

While solution by @GibboK did not work for me:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  action2: id => dispatch(Actions.action2(id)),
  action3: id => dispatch(Actions.action3(id)),
  action1: (dateId, attrId) => {
    return dispatch => {
      dispatch(Actions.action2(dateId));
      dispatch(Actions.action3(attrId));
    }
  }
});
```

I eventually went with [redux-batched-actions](https://github.com/tshelburne/redux-batched-actions). Worked like charm:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  action2: id => dispatch(Actions.action2(id)),
  action3: id => dispatch(Actions.action3(id)),
  action1: (dateId, attrId) =>
    dispatch(batchActions([
      Actions.action2(dateId),
      Actions.action3(attrId)
    ]))
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I solved it by creating a function that accepts object with the actions I want to  dispatch to the store and individual params for respective action

```
dispatchMultiple({params: {
    params1: "<arg for first action>" ,
    params2: "<arg for second action>",
                        },

})
const dispatchMultiple = (obj) => {
    dispatch(obj.actions.action1(obj.params.params1));
    dispatch(obj.actions.action2(obj.params.params2));
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me for synchronous multiple actions:

```js
// utils file
const multipleActions = (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(action1())
  dispatch(action2())
  dispatch(action3())
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
   onClickReturn: () => {
      multipleActions(dispatch)
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For guys in 2020...
The actions are Supposed to be made in the action Creater. For those who would like to dispatch an action and fetch/post some data from the API can use this Idea.

lets assume we have an `actions.js` file and we want to dispatch a loading action before fetch data.

```
function requestPosts() {
    return {
      type: "loading"
    }
  }
```

This is the fetching action function

```
function fetchPosts() {
 return dispatch => {
    // dispatch the loading
    dispatch(requestPosts());
    // fetch data from api
  return fetch("https://www.yoururl.com/api")
   .then(response => response.json())
   .then(json => dispatch({
       type: "fetching successful",
       payload: json
    }));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact use case but since redux uses asynchronous logic, any solution that runs the second dispatch in the next tick of the event loop should work.

```js
store.dispatch({ type: 'ADD_TODO', text: 'Buy milk.' });

setTimeout(() => {
  store.dispatch({ type: 'ADD_TODO', text: 'Take out garbage.' });
}, 0);

Promise.resolve(() => {
  store.dispatch({ type: 'ADD_TODO', text: 'Water plants.' });
});
```

If the second dispatch depends on the actions of first dispatch, you can get the state from the store, check if it satisfies the condition then dispatch the second action. It is best to keep the action's logic clean and granular.

So, to answer the question, the right place to dispatch multiple actions is inside the click handler where the first action originates.