# Two dispatch calls in mapDispatchToProps function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Due to my API, I need to get data in two separate calls. I have a generic redux-thunk async action that accepts parameters so it can be called a number of ways.

ShowPeopleContainer:

```
import { fetchPeople } from './actions';
import { getEmployees, getManagers } from './selectors';

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch({
   getData: () => {
    dispatch(fetchPeople('employees'));
    dispatch(fetchPeople('managers'));
   }
});

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  employees: getEmployees(state),
  managers: getManagers(state)
});
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(MyComponentPresentation)
```

ShowPeoplePresentation:

```
class ShowPeoplePresentation extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getData();
  }
  render() {
    return(
     <>
      <ShowPeople people={this.props.managers} />
      <ShowPeople people={this.props.employees} />
     </>
     );
   }
}
```

I don't think "getData" causes any side effects. Is it Ok to call dispatch twice like this?

Along these same lines, the redux docs seem to be putting a little bit of logic in the "Container Component" - see [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/examples/todos/src/containers/VisibleTodoList.js)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to dispatch multiple actions in redux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44321676/where-to-dispatch-multiple-actions-in-redux)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perfectly dispatch mutliple actions from within the `mapDispatchToProps` method, given that you are using redux-thunk.

Its however better and more readable if you simply add that logic while making `getData` as an action creator like

```
const getData = () => {
   return (dispatch) => {
       dispatch(fetchData('employees'));
       dispatch(fetchData('managers'));
   }
}
```

and use it like

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch({
   getData: () => {
    dispatch(getData());
   }
});
```

You could also dispatch fetchData and call it from within the component like

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch({
   fetchData: (type) => {
    dispatch(fetchData(type));
   }
});
```

and in component

```
getData = () => {
   const {fetchData} = this.props;
   fetchData('employees');
   fetchData('managers');
}
```

In the above solution you do not depend on `redux-thunk` to allow for multiple `dispatch`

Comment: I am coming from a MVVM background and our ViewModels would load all the data on init and it could be a lot of data. So it feels weird to create Component specific init methods into the kind of generic action creators module.

Comment: You could simply follow the second pattern which keeps the component specific logic within the component itself